# Replace a string with sequential counter, resetting the counter on each new line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file text (it's an index of names):

```
Variazione su Eraclito, <link-1262>§§§</link>
vecchio e il mare, <link-715>§§§</link>, <link-895>§§§</link>, <link-104>§§§</link> 
vento tra i salici, <link-355>§§§</link>
vergine e lo zingaro, <link-459>§§§</link>, <link-1564>§§§</link>
```

I have to add a progressive number at the content of <link-...>§§§</link> in place of §§§ as follows:

```
Variazione su Eraclito, <link-1262>1</link>
vecchio e il mare, <link-715>1</link>, <link-895>2</link>, <link-104>3</link> 
vento tra i salici, <link-355>1</link>
vergine e lo zingaro, <link-459>1</link>, <link-1564>2</link>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way with `awk`:

```
awk 'c=0;{while(match($0, /§§§/) > 0){c++;sub(/§§§/, c, $0)}};1' infile
```

It sets a `c`ounter and, as long as the line contains `§§§`, replaces each occurrence of `§§§` with the value of `c`ounter, incrementing the latter before every substitution.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$n = 0; s/§§§/++$n/ge' < file
```

To modify the file in-place:

```
perl -i -pe '$n = 0; s/§§§/++$n/ge' file
```